# Two pdf, same controller and same function but different page need to show show and hide contents based on condition using zend framework in dom pdf

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, dompdf

I am using DOM PDF and Zend Framework. I have two different pages like:

```
localhost:8083/gettingsign.php
localhost:8083/gettingapproved.php
```

In these two pages I am downloading a PDF. In that link I am using the same controller and same function but need to show in that PDF some content but not in other PDF I mean

```
if (localhost:8083/gettingsign.php) 
{  
    // if am in gettingsign.php and clicked pdf means want to show this condition
    $html . = " welcome to signing page ";
} 

if (localhost:8083/gettingapproved.php) 
{ 
    $html . = " welcome to approved page ";
}
```

Is it possible to get the `HTTP_REQUEST` page and send in to controller and check the condition in PDF? Please help me out with this.

Comment: You can't check the condition in the PDF. dompdf is just a renderer, so you'll want to fully render your HTML before sending it to dompdf. Add you condition to your HTML generation code.

Comment: Got solution guys.. Based on HTTP_REQUEST we can use the url condition to display different parts.